# How do i attach picture to table top-right corner with css?

Tags: html, css

I only have access to the css code so i can't edit the html. here's the page: http://myanimelist.net/animelist/linodiogo and the css code can be found here: http://pastebin.com/Kyz3dkmB. What i wanted to do was attach a transparent picture to the table right top corner so it would look better.

If you have any other recommendation I'm here to listen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following via CSS, however you would probably need access to the HTML to be able to incorporate this without affecting the layout of the rest of the table.

```
class/id {
    content:url(http://example.com)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure from the question/site what your aim is, but if you don't have access to the HTML it sounds as though an absolutely positioned pseudo-element might be the way to go here (even if you do have access to the HTML, it's still a good way to avoid clogged markup). The absolute positioning may avoid disruption to the table element.

Add position: relative to the table (or whatever you want the parent to be), and use the following to position a transparent element in the top-right:

```
parent:before {
    content: '';
    width: ...
    height: ...
    background: transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```